# tez session not getting started in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I am new to hadoop and yarn and tried running a hive insert query on hive 2 beeline. The Info I am getting is:
INFO  : Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
 and my system seemed to be hanged. 
I tried checking for the logs on YARN UI 8088 port and I am able to see my job killed

```
User:   hive
Name:   HIVE-e5f3af53-8861-4095-b6ea-4b6f28300ccc
Application Type:   TEZ
Application Tags:   
Application Priority:   0 (Higher Integer value indicates higher priority)
YarnApplicationState:   KILLED
Queue:  default
FinalStatus Reported by AM: KILLED
Started:    Wed Jan 23 17:15:07 +0530 2019
Elapsed:    8mins, 33sec
Tracking URL:   History
Log Aggregation Status: NOT_START
Application Timeout (Remaining Time):   Unlimited
Diagnostics:    Application application_1546858571448_0008 was killed by user hive at 10.5.3.113
Unmanaged Application:  false
Application Node Label expression:  <Not set>
AM container Node Label expression: <DEFAULT_PARTITION>
```

after checking the logs status in vi gc.log-201901071626 file in hdfs 
I am able to see GC allocation failure

```
2019-01-08T09:56:45.906+0530: 63044.883: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-08T09:56:45.906+0530: 63044.883: [ParNew: 106452K->1675K(118016K), 0.0137290 secs] 133048K->28271K(1035520K), 0.0138677 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2019-01-08T12:45:45.849+0530: 73184.825: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-01-08T12:45:45.849+0530: 73184.826: [ParNew: 106635K->940K(118016K), 0.0119422 secs] 133231K->27986K(1035520K), 0.0121155 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

Please help me in finding proper solution [image]

I tried changing engine to mr but it is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Is the tez client installed on the hiveserver? This is a requirement. 
You can also try lowering tez.am.resource.memory.mb